# Understanding the meaning of the integral of energy of an $\rm H$ atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, atomic-physics, units, hydrogen

This is probably very basic but my notes are confusing and not clearly written so I would appreciate some help in trying to clarify the following points:

If we consider the expression $$\left\langle \phi_{1s}(r_A)\left|-\frac{\nabla^2}{2}-\frac{1}{r_A}\right|\phi_{1s} (r_A)\right\rangle$$

where $\phi_{1s}(r_A)$ is the $1s$ orbital of the hydrogen atom centered on proton $A$ and $r_A$ denotes the position of the electron relative to the position of proton $A$.

My question regards the above expression. I know that this is equal to the energy of the hydrogen atom. Why do some sources write the solution of the expression as $-\frac{1}{2}$? My second question is whether this is equal to the ionisation energy of a hydrogen atom in its ground electronic state.

Comment: Somewhat aside from your question, but you seem to be mangling together Dirac and wavefunction notation in a way that does not really make sense. The ket $|\phi_{1s}\rangle$ describes the entire state of the electron. It does not make sense for it to have a spatial dependence. The wavefunction $\phi_{1s}(r_A) = \langle r_A|\phi_{1s}\rangle$ does have a spatial dependence but is a scalar quantity, not a ket.

Comment: @BySymmetry, along the same line of comment, also the expression of the Hamiltonian is clearly in the base of position. The real problem is that Dirac's notation is not easy to use in a consistent way and misuses like the present are sometimes found even in papers and textbooks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you find the ground state energy of the hydrogen atom expressed as $-\frac12$, it implies that the so-called [Hartree atomic units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartree_atomic_units) (a.u.) have been used. In such units $\frac{e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0}=1$, $\hbar=1$, and $m_e=1$. Therefore the ground state energy of the hydrogen atom, $E_{GS}=-\frac{m_ee^4}{2(4\pi\epsilon_0)^2\hbar^2}=-\frac12 a.u.$.

And, yes, $E_{GS}$ is also equal to the ionization energy since the underlying convention for the potential energy is to have it zero at an infinite distance from the nucleus.

Comment: In addition to this, the total energy of the hydrogen atom is M$_p$c$^2$+m$_e$c$^2$ plus the Schrödinger energy.

Comment: I assume its the same  as the ionisation energy only different in sign correct?

Comment: @DJA, yes, with the choice of the zero of energy I mentioned, the ionization energy is $-E_{GS}$.